# Soundcard not detected on Asus notebook

Tags: debian, audio

I am using an Asus machine.

Previouse to Debian i had Ubuntu Studio on the same notebook and the sound was working. Some information:

```
amir@debian:~$ lsb_release -d 
Description:    BunsenLabs GNU/Linux 9.8 (Helium)

amir@debian:~$ uname -r 
4.9.0-9-amd64

amir@debian:~$ grep "^audio" /etc/group | grep "$USER" | wc -l 
1

amir@debian:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio 
00:0e.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3198] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:129f]
00:0f.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:319a] (rev 03)

amir@debian:~$ dpkg -l | tr -s " " | grep " alsa-" 
ii alsa-firmware-loaders 1.1.3-1 amd64 ALSA software loaders for specific hardware
ii alsa-tools-gui 1.1.3-1 amd64 GUI based ALSA utilities for specific hardware
ii alsa-utils 1.1.3-1 amd64 Utilities for configuring and using ALSA

amir@debian:~$ lsmod | grep "snd"


amir@debian:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ head -n 3 /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 
head: cannot open '/proc/asound/card0/codec#0' for reading: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ head -n 3 /proc/asound/card0/codec97#0/ac97#0-0+regs 
head: cannot open '/proc/asound/card0/codec97#0/ac97#0-0+regs' for reading: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ aplay -l 
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...

amir@debian:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav 
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono (without hearing anything!)

amir@debian:~$ cat ~/.asoundrc 
cat: /home/amir/.asoundrc: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ cat /etc/asound.conf 
cat: /etc/asound.conf: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ cat ~/.asoundrc.asoundconf 
cat: /home/amir/.asoundrc.asoundconf: No such file or directory

amir@debian:~$ ps -C esd 
PID TTY          TIME CMD

amir@debian:~$ ps -C arts 
PID TTY          TIME CMD

amir@debian:~$ ps -C pulseaudio 
PID TTY          TIME CMD
1652 ?        00:00:36 pulseaudio
```

Comment: Please get the model number off the serial number plate and click [edit] then add the model to your original question, so we can find which sound adapter is built into our machine. Please do not click [Add Comment] as when new comments pile up, old ones get pushed off the page,.

Comment: install a kernel and the firmware-intel-sound (non-free) from backports then: `modprobe -v snd-soc-skl`.